# Partitioning MySQL table around unique data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization

I have a Mysql table with schema as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `historical_pricing` (
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double(20,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vol` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `date_idx` (`date`),
  KEY `company_idx` (`company`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

About 12GB of data is already loaded, and running a query to get distinct tickers doesn't finish in 15 minutes on a reasonable performance computer.

I have several microservices that looks up:

- List of all the companies we have data on `SELECT distinct(company) from historical_pricing`
- ALL the pricing data we have on each company `SELECT * FROM historical_pricing where company = 'AAPL' ORDER BY date desc`

I read through the MySQL 5.7 docs, and I think I can speed up the queries by **1)** partitioning by company name, and **2)** set up another index for date. There is a [8192 partition limit in MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations.html), so I was thinking of using partitions based on starting name: `a%`, `b%`, `1%`, `2%`, etc.

I'm trying to figure out:

- What's the proper MySQL ALTER TABLE syntax to add the partitions? I haven't been able to figure out if this is a list, range, etc.
- Does it make sense to do an index for company_date_idx (company first,
  and then date), or would a date_idx be enough since the index would be created within each partition?
- Is there a more effective way to optimize my queries?

**EDIT::**

I also have another index that does company, date as multi column index. What I noticed is that, regardless, each look up requires rerunning the entire table. I ran the following query if I should enlarge my `innodb_buffer_pool_size`:

```
SELECT engine,
  count(*) as TABLES,
  concat(round(sum(table_rows)/1000000,2),'M') rows,
  concat(round(sum(data_length)/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G') DATA,
  concat(round(sum(index_length)/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G') idx,
  concat(round(sum(data_length+index_length)/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G') total_size,
  round(sum(index_length)/sum(data_length),2) idxfrac
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE table_schema not in ('mysql', 'performance_schema', 'information_schema')
GROUP BY engine
ORDER BY sum(data_length+index_length) DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Result:

```
Engine  Table rows data idx total_size idxfrac
InnoDB  9   288.85M 36.28G  58.59G  94.87G  1.61
```

The machine only has 3.5GB of ram, and it set for 1GB to use for Mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Keep the ticker symbol.  (Which is it?? `id` or `company`??)
- Toss the other of `id` or `company`.
- Build a another table of companies -- ticker, company_name, etc.  This solves the first query by several orders of magnitude.
- Change to `PRIMARY KEY(ticker, date)`  This will be orders of magnitude better than simply `INDEX(ticker, date)`.  Why?  Because all the rows for the second query are adjacent to each other.  That is, you won't be bouncing around on disk for the `SELECT *`.

But, you should stop there.

Shrinking the datatypes helps avoid costly I/O...

- `DOUBLE(m,n)` is bad.  I wish they would get rid of that syntax.  It leads to two roundings.  Either say just `DOUBLE` or do something with `DECIMAL`.
- For `price`...  Thanks to BRK, you need at least 6 digits to the left of the decimal point.  Thanks to "penny" or nearly-delisted stocks, you need several decimal places.  Perhaps `DECIMAL(12, 6)` would do?  That takes 6 bytes (compared to 8 for `DOUBLE`).
- For `volume`... Some index funds can exceed 4 billion, so `INT UNSIGNED` is not sufficient.  Maybe you will need an 8-byte `DOUBLE`, or lose some precision with a 4-byte `FLOAT`.  Or go with some `DECIMAL`.
- Toss `created_at` and `updated_at` -- they are essentially useless.  And they take 10 bytes.

What about other queries?  In particular, you will be adding one new row for each ticker each day??  My suggested PK will work, though slowly, for it.  And, since you have all night to do the inserts, let's not add another index.

If you have any other queries, *then* we can consider `PARTITIONs`.  So far, partitioning will only slow things down.

Don't worry about "backward index scan".  The main cost to the query is the I/O, and I have solved that.

Notice how *each* of your queries now need to touch *consecutive* rows in some table.  This is as opposed to scanning a huge table (your query 1) or bouncing around between the index and the data (query 2).  So, no matter how 'cold' the cache is, my design will be much faster for both queries.

PS.  No secondary indexes are needed.

Answer (score 2):

Partitioning is less flexible than using an index. For example, keep in mind the rule documented on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html:

> "every unique key on the table must use every column in the table's partitioning expression"

This means your partitioning *cannot* use the company column, because that column is not part of your table's primary key.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE historical_pricing PARTITION BY KEY(company) PARTITIONS 37;
ERROR 1503 (HY000): A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function
```

Instead, I recommend you create a compound index. This takes the place of your single-column index on `company`.

```
ALTER TABLE historical_pricing 
  DROP KEY company_idx, ADD KEY (company, date);
```

This will help optimize both queries:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT company FROM historical_pricing;
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table              | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | historical_pricing | NULL       | index | company       | company | 19      | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM historical_pricing WHERE company = 'AAPL' ORDER BY date DESC;
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | partitions | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                            |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | historical_pricing | NULL       | ref  | company       | company | 15      | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Backward index scan |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------------------------------+
```

(Note the "Backward index scan" is an optimization in MySQL 8.0. MySQL 5.7 can scan an index backwards too, but at higher cost. See https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-descending-indexes-in-mysql/)

Comment: I added some more info about the indexes I have. It looks like Mysql can't store everything in memory. Is that a high possibility? If so, is that something I can work around easily?

Comment: It's not usually true that you need *all* the data and indexes to fit in RAM. InnoDB is designed to keep the most frequently-used pages in RAM. At my company, we tend to have a general rule that the InnoDB buffer pool is configured to about 1/10th the size of the database (data + indexes). In some cases we might adjust this up or down, but it's a good starting point.